# How to change the src of imageview on re-click

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have one ImageView with src, and I want it to change its src onClick. That's easy, but I want to change it's src back to normal when user clicks the imageview again. How can I make it in java?

**EDIT:**

I already tried this:

```
    public void act1 (View view) {
    ImageView ic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id1);

    Drawable oldBg = ic1.getBackground();
    String oldBgStr = ic1.getBackground().toString();

    Drawable ic1light = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic1);
    Drawable ic1dark = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic1dark);

    ic1.setTag(R.drawable.ic1);

    if (oldBg == ic1light){
        ic1.setBackground(ic1dark);
    }
    if (oldBg == ic1dark) {
        ic1.setBackground(ic1light);
    }

    ic1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1dark);
}
```

Here is XML of ImageView and Layout it's in:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="act1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: Do you have some code to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set a boolean and toggle it whenever the user clicks on the image. Check the boolean each time and display the appropriate image.

```
private boolean mClicked = false;

public void act1 (View view) {
    if(mClicked) {
        ic1.setBackground(ic1dark);
    }
    else {
        ic1.setBackground(ic1light);
    }

    mClicked = !mClicked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean to switch between states of current image set like so:

```
 private boolean currentState = false;

 public void act1 (View view) {
    ImageView ic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id1);

    // set current src


    Drawable oldBg = ic1.getBackground();
    String oldBgStr = ic1.getBackground().toString();

    Drawable ic1light = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic1);
    Drawable ic1dark = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic1dark);

    ic1.setTag(R.drawable.ic1);

    // when this is called from click event of anything else
    if(currentState){
        ic1.setBackground(ic1light);
        currentState = true;
        return;
    }

    if(!currentState){
        ic1.setBackground(ic1dark);
        currentState = false;
        return;
    }

  }
```